How do find the derivative of $f(x):=\int_0^{x^2}\cos\left(\pi t^2\right)\operatorname dt$?

Let $f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}\cos\left(\pi t^2\right)\operatorname dt$. Find $f^\prime(x)$.

We need to find
$$\frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dx}\int_0^{x^2}\cos\left(\pi t^2\right)\operatorname dt.$$
I tried to exchange the operators, which probably gives
$$\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dx}\cos\left(\pi t^2\right)\operatorname dt.$$
Since $\cos\left(\pi t^2\right)$ doesn't contain $x$, the above is equal to
$$\int_0^{x^2}0\operatorname dt=0.$$
Where did I do wrong?

In general, it is not true that
$$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\dv}[2]{\frac{\dd #1}{\dd #2}}
\dv{}{x} \int_\ast^\ast f(x) \, \dd x 
= \int_\ast^\ast \dv f x \, \dd x
$$
This is your main mistake, and this is a problematic misconception regardless of the bounds $\ast$ in the integral. For instance,
$$
\dv{}{x} \int x^2 \, \dd x = \dv{}{x} \left( \frac 1 3 x^3 + C \right) = x^2
$$
whereas
$$
\int \dv{}{x} x^2 \, \dd x = \int 2x \, \dd x = x^2 + C
$$
which are not equivalent expressions. You can only imagine how bad this might get if bounds are specified. For instance,
$$
\int_0^1 x^2 \, \dd x = \frac 1 3
$$
Hence
$$
\dv{}{x} \int_0^1 x^2 \, \dd x = 0
$$
Meanwhile,
$$
\int_0^1 2x \, \dd x = 1
$$
so
$$
\int_0^1 \dv{}{x} x^2 \, \dd x = \int_0^1 2x \, \dd x = 1 \ne 0
$$
So, in general, integrals and derivatives are not interchangeable!!

To help you along, first define
$$\begin{align*}
I(x) &= \int_0^x \cos \pi t^2 \, \dd t \\
f(x) &= x^2 \\
\end{align*}$$
Because of this, then, you seek
$$
\dv{}{x} I(f(x))
$$
for which the chain rule readily applies. Don't forget how to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, since
$$
\dv{}{x} \int_a^x g(t) \, \dd t = g(x)
$$
provided $g$ is continuous at $x$.

Uh, in general,
$\displaystyle \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \int_{\mathcal {a} \left( x \right)}^{\mathcal {b} \left( x \right)} \mathcal {f} \left( t \left| \, x \right. \right) \text {d} t = {\bigg[ \mathcal {f} \left( u \left| \, x \right. \right) \cdot \frac {\text {d} u}{\text {d} x} \bigg]}_{u = \mathcal {a} \left( x \right)}^{u = \mathcal {b} \left( x \right)} + \int_{\mathcal {a} \left( x \right)}^{\mathcal {b} \left( x \right)} \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \mathcal {f} \left( t \left| \, x \right. \right) \text {d} t. \tag*{}$
In your case $\mathcal {a} \left( x \right) = 0$, $\mathcal {b} \left( x \right) = {x}^{2}$, and $\mathcal {f} \left( t \left| \, x \right. \right) = \cos ( \pi {t}^{2} )$, so
$\displaystyle \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \int_{0}^{{x}^{2}} \cos ( \pi {t}^{2} ) \text {d} t = 2 x \cot ( \pi {x}^{4} ). \tag*{}$
This is known as the Leibniz integral rule.

Perhaps you can write $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

@Gary, I have made the edit. Hope it is okay now.
